# How can I find the nearest distance between points in a 2D array and a 3D matrix grid?

Tags: python

I have buoy data as an array of longitudes and latitudes for 30 days, however I would like to find the closest distance between the buoys' locations and the 0% sea ice concentration for each day. The sea ice concentration data is a 3D matrix, however the space dimensions are in x y coordinates not latitudes and longitudes. 
I have converted all the concentrations above 0% to Nan. I am not to sure now how to locate the closest latitude+longitude points of the sea ice to each point along the buoy trajectory.

This is my ice dataset:

Dimensions:                (time: 363, x: 2528, y: 2656)

Coordinates:

- y                      (y) int16 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 2652 2653 2654 2655 2656
- x                      (x) int16 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 2524 2525 2526 2527 2528
- time                   (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01T12:00:00 ... 2017-12-30T12:00:00

  longitude              (time, y, x) float32 dask.array

  latitude               (time, y, x) float32 dask.array

Data variables:

```
sea_ice_concentration  (time, y, x) float32 dask.array<shape=(363, 2656, 2528), chunksize=(1, 2656, 2528)>

land                   (time, y, x) int8 dask.array<shape=(363, 2656, 2528), chunksize=(1, 2656, 2528)>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please bear in mind that we are not behind your screen to see what is wrong. Please post a [mcve] showing your problem and you may get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Djikstras shortest path algorithm](http://benalexkeen.com/implementing-djikstras-shortest-path-algorithm-with-python/). The link contains an example in python which could be your starting point.

You will then need to convert your results, which will be in x,y dimensions to latitude/longitude.